Maui project doesnt build
When building my Maui project with platform specific code i get the errors:
Microsoft.Android.Sdk.RuntimeConfig.targets(61, 5): [MSB4062] The "RuntimeConfigParserTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly <path>. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<value>' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
And
RuntimeComponentManifest.targets(14, 5): [MSB4175] The task factory "JsonToItemsTaskFactory.JsonToItemsTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly <path>. Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=<value>' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
I use .net 8 and my build targets of the project are net8.0-android;net8.0-ios. It looks like my project wants to access a Microsoft package (System.Text.Json) thats for .net 7. However i never specified this package and when i did with the .net 8 variant the system still threw these errors. I tried looking this up but i couldnt find anything related. Does anyone know how i can resolve these errors?
Also i do use rider as an IDE. I did verify that the workloads are installed and also that the msbuild version is the latest (17.0).

Are you able to reproduce this with a completely "vanilla" project? If not, have you worked out a minimal project that demonstrates the problem? Do you have any other dependencies?

With a vanilla project i dont have this issue so i probably have configured something poorly. When building the vanilla app i also dont get any warnings and in my project i do get a lot of warnings saying "Warning NETSDK1213 : Targeting .NET 8.0 or higher in Visual Studio 2022 17.7 is not supported.". I did check all my projects but they all have TargetFrameworks .net 8. I will try to create a minimal project that demonstrates the issue

Turns out the installation source of the workloads need to be from the SDKs and not from VS. You can check this by running the command dotnet workload list. If the Installation Source of maui, maui-android and maui-ios are from vs then it doesn't work. I installed the SDKs by running the command dotnet workload install maui this downloaded the SDKs. For me, I also have a second installation source from VS now but this doesn't seem to matter.
